# Apache Camel : How to log the process happening in the syntax from(file:).to(to:)

Tags: logging, apache-camel

Need to log the source, end point and transaction in the configure method

```
main(String args[]){
 CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
 context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
    from("file:location).to("file:location")}});
 context.start
}
```

Comment: Camel should print some of this information through DEBUG statements already. Have you tried looking into the log component or using a processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tracer

- http://camel.apache.org/tracer

Also Camel uses regular logging, so you can enable DEBUG level on org.apache.camel etc and get a lot of verbose logging.

But for end user logging the tracer is more appropriate as it logs the steps in the routing.

Comment: Thanks Claus Ibsen it helps